# Webmaster Tools doesn't like my page set pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search-engine, google-search-console, search-engine-bots

I'm trying to use the highlighting feature on Webmaster tools. I got done filling it out for my page, but when I go and try to create the page set, it doesn't find any files matching the pattern.

The default pattern that google chose is:

```
http://www.example.com/*/*/*/*
```

That's not good enough because that's everything on my site.

What I want is this:

```
http://www.example.com/Team/Schedule/*/*
```

It can't find this. The first asterisk is just the id, and the second * is the name associated with that id.

I tried adding this:

```
http://www.example.com/Team/Schedule/*
```

It can't find anything here either.

This DOES work

```
http://www.example.com/Team/*/*/*
```

So, why doesn't the pattern that I want get recognized? I've even tried copying and pasting in the "Team/Schedule" portion to make I didn't misspell, but that still doesn't work.

**Edit:**

the "template" path that I used for the highlighting looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Team/Schedule/105/Bears
```

And similar pages would be:

```
http://www.example.com/Team/Schedule/52/Vikings
```

Comment: This is weird, just today, the above example started working. I made NO changes to the route structure, or anything like that. But other route patterns that are similar (but like /Team/Roster/*/*) are not working. I guess I'll need to wait a few more days before those will start working.

Comment: This was a result of Google containing an old cached version of my page structures. I had just recently updated the structure, and Google had not re-crawled to get those changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of Google containing an old cached version of my page structures. I had just recently updated the structure, and Google had not re-crawled to get those changes.